# Button css to disable button

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Iam new to bootstrap. I tried to use Bootstrap to manage the button logic inside my app but I am confused.

I found this JavaScript code:

```
$('#reportButton').prop('disabled', true);
$('#reportButton').prop('disabled', false);
```

If I set disabled to true the button is disabled but in a very low way. The Events are blocked but the button do not look really professional. The cursor is the same as on the whole page and if the button use the btn-sm for small button the button will not change its color means it looks like active.

There is also no change if I add:

```
$('#reportButton').addClass('disabled');
```

This confuses me. What is the best way to make it appear disabled and have a disabled cursor on hover?

I use:
https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js
https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js

Added Information:
Button code:

```
<button type="button" class="btn-primary btn-sm" id="logoutButton">Logout</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" style="width:802px;" id="reportButton">Report Anzeigen</button>
```

The JavaScript is:

```
const sendCase = document.getElementById('sendButton');

  function disableButtons(stateSwitch){
        $('#logoutButton').prop('disabled', stateSwitch);
        $('#reportButton').prop('disabled', stateSwitch);
    }

sendCase.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    disableButtons(true);
});
```

```js
const sendCase = document.getElementById('sendButton');

function disableButtons(stateSwitch) {
  $('#logoutButton').prop('disabled', stateSwitch);
  $('#reportButton').prop('disabled', stateSwitch);
}

sendCase.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  disableButtons(true);
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" class="btn-primary btn-sm" id="logoutButton">Logout</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" style="width:802px;" id="reportButton">Report Anzeigen</button>
```

Comment: A question like "How do I make this look professional?" is likely to generate opinionated answers, and is generally off-topic for Stack Overflow. How do you want the disabled button to look? Once you specify that, it will be easier for others to help.

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: I've read the question again and still have the same feedback, even in light of your new additions. I would suggest adding that you'd like the cursor to change to "not allowed", if that's your goal, as @ciammarino has inferred. The question does not state your desired result, other than to make it like a "professional UI".

Comment: I've added a snippet of your code, however you do not have an element with an id of "sendButton" in the included HTML, so nothing gets disabled. You should [edit] your question so that running the snippet reproduces the problem you're seeing. Also, "professional" is indeed in the eye of the beholder. I've built hundreds of websites for as many clients and they've all looked different...

Comment: @Sean Maybe just a description from not fluent English speaker? However, Everything was inside my question and others than you did understood the question.

Comment: @indo I didn't think that you might want a disabled cursor until I saw the answer from another user, who guessed at what you meant by "professional". I've suggested an edit based on this exchange to help you get good answers.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a class to the button which will display a "not allowed" cursor when hovered over the button.

```js
 $('#reportButton').prop('disabled', true);
 $('#reportButton').addClass('disabled');
```

```css
.disabled{
  cursor:not-allowed;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <button class="btn btn-primary" id="reportButton">Click</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ciammarino/xomjew21/13/

Comment: I saw in https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_buttons.asp that bootstrap will do this cursor thing for us. Maybe I use a newer version?

Comment: What about the btn-sm .... This keep in active style if I disable this. Is this a bug in bootstrap?

Comment: I added the class btn-sm to the jsfiddle and it's still working correctly.

Comment: Ok, I think I missed btn. So the right code is "btn btn-primary btn-sm" I just used "btn-primary btn-sm"

Comment: Awesome! You got this! If you don't like the disabled background color bootstrap provides, you can override it in your code. I adjusted the jsfiddle so you can see. Also, I would recommend using percentages for a large button rather than pixels. Pixels are an absolute so no matter what size the screen is the button will always be 802px. I changed it to 80% but you can play with it.